# OAuth2: (Why) does exchanging authorization code for access token require authorization header?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm reading [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) defining OAuth2 and in [section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) (about the  Authorization Code Grant) it seems to state that when a client is exchanging authorization code for access token, the request needs to include `authorization` header (see section 4.1.3 specifically).

- Is it indeed required for all such requests or maybe I understand it
  wrong and it's only required for a subset of such requests? If so,
  what is the subset?
- If it is required, then why? I thought that the authorization code is enough to prove that the client is authorized to get the token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes from [section 2.3 Client Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3).

If the client type is confidential, the client and authorization server establish a client authentication method suitable for the security requirements of the authorization server.  The authorization server MAY accept any form of client authentication meeting its security requirements.

Confidential clients are typically issued (or establish) a set of client credentials used for authenticating with the authorization server (e.g., password, public/private key pair).

The authorization server MAY establish a client authentication method with public clients.  However, the authorization server MUST NOT rely on public client authentication for the purpose of identifying the client.

[Section 2.1 Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)

> OAuth defines two client types, based on their ability to authenticate
> securely with the authorization server (i.e., ability to maintain the
> confidentiality of their client credentials):
>
> **confidential**
>
> Clients capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
> credentials (e.g., client implemented on a secure server with
> restricted access to the client credentials), or capable of secure
> client authentication using other means.
>
> **public**
>
> Clients incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
> credentials (e.g., clients executing on the device used by the
> resource owner, such as an installed native application or a web
> browser-based application), and incapable of secure client
> authentication via any other means.

**Summary**

The requirement for an authorization header is determined by the authorization server and is implementation specific.

Comment: So the authorization header is used to authenticate the client (i.e. a 3rd party app) and not the resource owner? I'm implementing the authorization server by the way. Can I decide to not support confidential clients at all? And if I do so, what exactly will be insecure in the communication? Thanks!

Comment: You can decided to implement the `Authorization` header or not. It is up to your design.

Comment: If I don't implement it, do I lose anything in terms of security for the resource owner? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: Since you are implementing the authorization server, you decide on the security mechanisms. Do you loose anything? Depends on your design. OAuth 2.0 is somewhat complicated and mistakes can create holes that can be breached.